# How to pass task parameter into dependsOn method in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a task which copies reports:

```
task copyReports(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn = ['cleanTest', 'test -i']
        from 'build/reports/tests/test/classes'
        into 'reports'
        println 'FINISHED COPYING FILES'
}
```

This task depends on `cleanTest` and `test`. I want to run `test` task with the parameter `-i` to see output of the tests. How to pass this parameter into `dependsOn` method? At the moment I get the next error:

```
Task with path 'test -i' not found in root project
```

I also tried without single quotes. Like this:

```
dependsOn = [cleanTest, test -i]
```

Then I get the next error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'i' for task ':copyReports' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another angle is to set the log-level for the `test` task, but that could be tricky, based on this open issue - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1010

Comment: Apart passing the `-i` parameter globally, i don't think it's possible